# pygame collisions with bullets cannot find collisions and bullets disappear

Tags: python, oop, pygame, collision, kill

When I run my code the program says to me:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\two_player_gun_game.py", line 192, in <module>
    if player_one_bullet.is_collided_with(player_two):
NameError: name 'player_one_bullet' is not defined
```

I do not understand why this reason comes up I have created a function in one of the classes which is is_collided_with but. it still seems not to work can. I have put at the bottom an if statement which checks for collisions. colllisions are meant to be happening for player 1 and 2's bullets. Here is my code to help:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
pygame.display.set_caption("this game")


class Background:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/images/space.jpg").convert()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (1280, 720))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))


class player_first:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/ezgif.com-crop.gif")
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (200, 200))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.ypos += self.speed_y

    def draw(self):      #left right
        #screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, True, False), self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))


class player_second:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/Giantmechanicalcrab2 - Copy.gif")
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (300, 200))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.ypos += self.speed_y

    def draw(self):      #left right
        #screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, True, False), self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))







class player_one_Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/giphy.gif").convert_alpha()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))


    def __init__(self):
        self.xpos = 360
        self.ypos = 360
        self.speed_x = 0
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))
        #self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, False, True), self.rect)

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)


class player_two_Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/MajesticLavishBackswimmer-size_restricted.gif").convert_alpha()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))
    picture = pygame.transform.rotate(picture, 180)


    def __init__(self):
        self.xpos = 360
        self.ypos = 360
        self.speed_x = 0
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos -= self.speed_x

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))
        #self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, False, True), self.rect)

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)


player_one = player_first(0, 0)
player_two = player_second(1000, 0)
cliff = Background(0, 0)
player_one_bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_two_bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()



while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player_one.speed_y = -5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player_one.speed_y = 5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player_two.speed_y = -5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player_two.speed_y = 5







                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    player_one_bullet = player_one_Bullet()

                    player_one_bullet.ypos = player_one.ypos
                    player_one_bullet.xpos = player_one.xpos

                    player_one_bullet.speed_x = 14

                    player_one_bullet_list.add(player_one_bullet)



                elif event.key == pygame.K_KP0:
                    player_two_bullet = player_two_Bullet()

                    player_two_bullet.ypos = player_two.ypos
                    player_two_bullet.xpos = player_two.xpos

                    player_two_bullet.speed_x = 14

                    player_two_bullet_list.add(player_two_bullet)




            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                # Stop moving when the keys are released.
                if event.key == pygame.K_s and player_one.speed_y > 0:
                    player_one.speed_y = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w and player_one.speed_y < 0:
                    player_one.speed_y = 0


                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and player_two.speed_y > 0:
                    player_two.speed_y = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and player_two.speed_y < 0:
                    player_two.speed_y = 0


    if player_one_bullet.is_collided_with(player_two):  
            player_one_bullet.kill()


    if player_two_bullet.is_collided_with(player_one):  
            player_two_bullet.kill()

    player_one.update()
    player_two.update()
    cliff.draw()
    player_one.draw()
    player_two.draw()

    player_one_bullet_list.update()
    player_two_bullet_list.update()

    for player_one_bullet in player_one_bullet_list:
            player_one_bullet.draw()


    for player_two_bullet in player_two_bullet_list:
            player_two_bullet.draw()

    for player_one_bullet in player_one_bullet_list.sprites():
        if player_one_bullet.is_collided_with(player_two):
            player_one_bullet.kill()

    for player_two_bullet in player_two_bullet_list.sprites():
        if player_two_bullet.is_collided_with(player_one):
            player_two_bullet.kill()



    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I have now added what another persons answer was but unfortunately not as soon as the bullet.draw() function happens the bullet suddenly goes off the screen

still confused can you show me the code please, that would help.

Comment: @Blckknght can you show me where it needs to be in the code please. that would help me much more.

Comment: @Blckknght this did not work and the bullets are still disappearing

Comment: @skrx do you know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in the scope of the elif statement. Move it to here, and set it to None and then assign it in the elif:

```
player_one = player_first(0, 0)
player_two = player_second(1000, 0)
cliff = Background(0, 0)
player_one_bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_two_bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_one_bullet = None
player_two_bullet = None
```

Comment: what do I assign the player one and two bullets in the elif statement

Comment: thank you this really useful and I have managed to achieve loads